# How to set a header image?

Tags: header-image

I can get the image header with

> get_header_image()

ex:

```
wp eval "echo get_header_image();"
```

But how can I change that ?
I tried

set_header_image(url) and Custom_Image_Header::set_header_image

with no success.

Comment: are you using default theme or customized theme?

Comment: I installed a theme

Comment: Which theme are u using?

Comment: Used theme:  EnvestPro Lite. It is a classic theme where you set the image header in customize->theme->header

Answer (score 0):

`get_header_image()` uses `get_theme_mod()` to get the saved header image, so I would assume the following example should be used to update the saved value. And `set_header_image` does the same thing at the end of it, after all the different checks.

```
set_theme_mod( 'header_image' , 'your-image-url-here' );
```